# How to send email automatically at a particular time every day

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

How to send e-mail automatically at 11am every day using ASP.NET, C#, Webforms?

I am doing on button click to send mail. My requirement is every day, at 11 am, that mail should be sent automatically. Is this possible using C# code?

```
protected void SendEmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
   {
       using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
       {
           gv_TotalAllReg.RenderControl(hw);
           StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
           MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("techhelp@xyz.com", "xyz@xyz.com,xyz1@xyz.com");

           mm.Subject = "Daily Report";

           mm.Body = "Dear Customer, <br><br>Applications received as on: " + ViewState["date"] + ".<hr />" + sw.ToString() + "<br/>Thanks,<br>Support Team.";

           mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
           mm.CC.Add("my@no.com");

           SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
           smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
           smtp.EnableSsl = true;

           System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
           NetworkCred.UserName = "no@gmail.com";
           NetworkCred.Password = "n0";
           smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
           smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
           smtp.Port = 587;

           smtp.Send(mm);

           lbl_msg.Visible = true;
       }
   }
}
```

Below is my button code.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSendEmail" runat="server" Text="Send email" OnClick="SendEmail" class="btn btn-md btn-danger pull-right" />
```

When I will button click then gridview data is sending to emails. But I am trying like below concept.

```
   If(time==11am)
   {
     //send mail
   }
```

I search lot but got Windows Service related example but I am not getting that type of concept. Is there any other ways.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use a job scheduler library.

Use [hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) or [Quartz.net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

You will be able to schedule a job a specific time.

With hangfire it will be like this:

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => SendMail(), 
    new DateTime(2017, 27, 03, 11, 00, 00));
```

Comment: I am working using asp.net web forms application. Is there any sample code to achieve fastly. @Ygalbel

Comment: @mazhar124 If you want it fastly, I suggest you hire some experienced developer to do it for you?!?

Comment: I am developer only but new that please help to out. @UweKeim

Comment: job scheduler library is free. @Ygalbel

Comment: Sacha barber has a fine getting started with Quartz.net over at codeproject: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/860893/Scheduling-With-Quartz-Net

Comment: Just I have to add this labrary and the above code and check mail is going or not, one more doubt is there (2017, 27, 03, 11, 00, 00) date should dynamic ? or not. @Ygalbel

Comment: Note that this assumes the website is [actually running](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html) at the appropriate time. It's often better to run Hangfire in a separate Windows service process and queue the background jobs from the website.

Comment: @mazhar124 date should be dynamic. Check `DateTime` class.

Comment: How can I download library not able to find in the site http://hangfire.io/. @Ygalbel

Comment: I have to install like that on nuget: Install-Package HangFire . @Ygalbel

Answer (score 2):

A web forms applications is the wrong place for scheduled tasks for several reasons. First, web forms it is based on the request-response paradigm of http. This means that server code is triggered by http requests, e.g. when a user browses a page or clicks on a button. Theoretically, you could implement an infinite loop that checks for the condition (i.e. utilizing sleep or even a timer) and then sends the message, which is executed by `SendMail`. However, this is a bad idea as the IIS application pool your webforms application is running in might be recycled.

As an alternative, you can

- create a console application that is performing the mail send task and execute it using the Windows task scheduler, or
- create a windows service that performs the send mail task, or
- use any other task scheduling utility to execute a console app or call a web service.

Comment: @mazhar124 For the first methods you just put the send mail code in the `Main` method of a console application, and execute it using the [Task Scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx). There are [tutorials](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Tutorial-to-create-a-simple-Windows-Service-with-sample-example-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx) on how to create a windows service with a time. The third option of using task scheulding libraries is described in the answer of @Ygalbel.

Comment: I am sending mail of gridview data and gridview will not working in console. @Gaste

Comment: Why will the gridview not work in a console application? [You can use the ASP.NET controls in a console application.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1018819/2623126)

Comment: ok, can you help one more. I am trying this code: BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => SendMail(), 
    new DateTime(2017, 27, 03, 11, 00, 00)); .@Gaste

Comment: I added this code in page load but getting error: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime. @Gaste

Comment: I need to send at 11 am that email. @Gaste

Comment: It does not work because there is no 27th month ...  the second argument of the constructor is the month, not the day

Comment: How to pass 11 am, please tell me from this code. @Gaste

Comment: Refer to the [`DateTime` API documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)